# Что именно не так с моим кодом на Си? (Простенькая программка)

Tags: c, алгоритм, циклы, консоль

Подскажите пожалуйста начинающему программисту что не так с кодом. Ошибка здесь наверняка не одна. Компилятор возвращает лишь нули но ответы в том количестве в котором требуется.
Суть программки заключается в следующем: пользователь задает ей начальные и конечные значения X а так же шаг изменения переменной, программа же должна пропускать x через две формулы и из двух результатов возвращать наибольший и так для каждого шага.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NUM 108

double startX, deltaX, endX, x, f1, f2;

double function1(){
f1 = log(1-NUM/sin(x));
return 0;
}

double function2(){
f2 = tan(x)/NUM;
return 0;
}

double decideFUNC(){
for(x = startX; x <= endX; x += deltaX){
    function1();
    function2();
if(function1==function2)
printf("max values are the same %f\n", function1);
else{
    if (function1>function2) 
        printf("%f\n", f1);
    else printf("%f\n",f2);
    }
}
return 0;
}
int main(){
  printf("Enter start value X: \n");
  scanf("%d", &startX);
  printf("Enter delta X:  \n");
  scanf("%d", &deltaX);
  printf("Enter ending value X: \n");
  scanf("%d", &endX);
  decideFUNC();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(function1==function2)` и `if (function1>function2)` - что здесь сравнивается? Компилятор вам ясно указал на грубые ошибки в этих строчках. Вы просто проигнорировали диагностические сообщения компилятора?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 108

double startX, deltaX, endX;

double function1(double x) {
  return log(1 - NUM / sin(x));
}

double function2(double x) {
  return tan(x) / NUM;
}


double decideFUNC(){
  double x, f1, f2;
  for(x = startX; x <= endX; x += deltaX) {
    f1 = function1(x);
    f2 = function2(x);
    if (f1 == f2) { // вряд ли мы сюда попадем
      printf("max values are the same %f\n", f1);
    } else {
      if (f1 > f2) 
        printf("x = %f, f1 = %f (%f, %f)\n", x, f1, f1, f2);
      else 
        printf("x = %f, f2 = %f (%f, %f)\n", x, f2, f1, f2);
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  startX = 40;
  deltaX = 4;
  endX = 100;
  decideFUNC();
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
x = 40.000000, f2 = -0.010345 (nan, -0.010345)                                                                                                                               
x = 44.000000, f2 = 0.000164 (nan, 0.000164)                                                                                                                                 
x = 48.000000, f1 = 4.952854 (4.952854, 0.011112)                                                                                                                            
x = 52.000000, f2 = -0.056049 (nan, -0.056049)                                                                                                                               
x = 56.000000, f1 = 5.337897 (5.337897, -0.005660)                                                                                                                           
x = 60.000000, f1 = 5.873014 (5.873014, 0.002963)                                                                                                                            
x = 64.000000, f2 = 0.021739 (nan, 0.021739)                                                                                                                                 
x = 68.000000, f1 = 4.798077 (4.798077, -0.018890)                                                                                                                           
x = 72.000000, f2 = -0.002430 (nan, -0.002430)                                                                                                                               
x = 76.000000, f2 = 0.006359 (nan, 0.006359)                                                                                                                                 
x = 80.000000, f1 = 4.697422 (4.697422, 0.083367)                                                                                                                            
x = 84.000000, f2 = -0.009983 (nan, -0.009983)                                                                                                                               
x = 88.000000, f2 = 0.000328 (nan, 0.000328)                                                                                                                                 
x = 92.000000, f1 = 4.938469 (4.938469, 0.011521)                                                                                                                            
x = 96.000000, f2 = -0.050475 (nan, -0.050475)                                                                                                                               
x = 100.000000, f1 = 5.367305 (5.367305, -0.005437)
```

https://onlinegdb.com/SkwGxSI7E

Comment: Igor, к сожалению все-равно не работает. Консоль выводить лишь Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт, 2009. Все права защищены.

C:\Users\Батя>cd ../../c

C:\C>gcc test.c -o test

C:\C>test
Enter start value X:
40
Enter delta X:
4
Enter ending value X:
100
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000

C:\C>

Comment: А если вместо `#define NUM 108` написать `#define NUM 108f`? (Так сказать, wild guess).

Comment: @Сергей Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Answer (score 0):

1. Каждая из двух функций возвращает 0, причем возвращает в никуда.
2. В if-ах сравнивается непонятно что.

Для начала нужно разобраться с этими двумя пунктами.